# How to get custom (non-player) heads in minecraft 1.10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have seen a tutorial to do this, the one with changing your skin, but I'm using it with /summon and the ArmorItems NBT tag (The head is only present *while* the player is playing it), and I want my map to work whenever someone decides to play it.

Comment: please , be more specific and try to give us photos of your creation you made so far. I don't understood anything you tried to explain

Answer (score 1):

Do `/give (your player name) Minecraft:command_block` and inside the command block type `/give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"[username]"}`
At the `[username]` type the players name that you want and yeah.
Do ruthless tomato his my favourite!

Comment: A couple of formatting tips. Don't bold the whole message. Bolding is supposed to be for **emphesis**. Use preformatting for code sections. Makes them stand out better. For line break, `space-space-enter`. Or, for new paragraph, `enter-enter`.